# Problem with R studio on Mac with Monterey and arm system

Tags: java, r, rjava

I have this error message and I don't know how to solve it

> Loading required namespace: rJava Failed with error: ‘.onLoad failed
> in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details: call: dyn.load(jli, FALSE)
> error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Internet
> Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib':
> dlopen(/Library/Internet
> Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib,
> 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Internet
> Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib'
> (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
> 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libjli.dylib' (no such file)’ Cannot load rJava
> Error in .local(x, p, ...) : maxent() is not TRUE

Comment: Sounds like you have an M1 Mac, but installed an x86-64 (Intel/AMD) Java. That said, applets are outdated technology, so it is suspicious something is even trying to load something applet related.

Comment: Download Java with `ARM 64` - https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-mac ; Make sure you are using `ARM 64` version of `rJava` as well. Also, make sure to set your Java version (inside system) to the version you want to user `ARM 64`. You can do it by setting `JAVA_HOME` and exporting `PATH` such way it points to your Java version. Then, run `R` from `CLI`. Also, it might be required to setup your `Java` env inside `R`: https://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava/