# Macbook Pro M1 issues connecting to oracle database with R

Tags: java, r, oracle, rjava, rjdbc

I am using an M1 MBP running Monterey and trying to connect to an oracle database to pull data into R. Currently I am trying to setup RJDBC but am open to other options if there is something easier to use.

When I try to load RJDBC I am getting:

```
Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(jli, FALSE)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib':
  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib, 0x000A): tried: '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libjli.dylib' (no such file)
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
```

I have seen a few similar posts:

- [How to install rJava package in Mac with M1 architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67849830/how-to-install-rjava-package-in-mac-with-m1-architecture)
- [Problem with R studio on Mac with Monterey and arm system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70021254/problem-with-r-studio-on-mac-with-monterey-and-arm-system)

And am wondering what the best course of action here is. Would it be better to try and instal the arm version of java or the arm version of R?

Comment: I think your problem is that applet.  Nobody should be using applets anymore.  My guess is that the R JDBC access has not been updated in a very, very long time.  I wonder if it needs attention.

Answer (score 1):

*JavaAppletPlugin* no longer exists.

[*Java Applet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) technology has been retired, [phased out](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/398) across all platforms including macOS.

See Oracle white paper, [*Java Client Roadmap Update*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf).

Contact the app publisher for an updated modern release. The release you have must be from many years ago.

Comment: Whats the best solution in this case? It seems when I attempt to load RJDBC it is calling rJava and rJava is looking for the appletplugin.

Comment: @user3249770 Contact the publisher of that app for an updated modern release.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by downloading ARM version of java:

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-mac